# TurtleBot BringUp Errors

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-bringup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, (*Warning: I'm new to TurtleBot, ROS, and UBUNTU*)

I'm having trouble bringing up my TurtleBot. I installed Ubuntu 11.04 Natty and ROS on my Laptop/TurtleBot and my Workstation. I setup the network settings, but skipped making a VPN. I made it as far as SSH-ing into my Laptop/TurtleBot.

Here is my Play by Play

1. Turn on Laptop, log in, close lid, plug into TurtleBot/Kinect, turn on iCreate
2. Turn on Workstation, open terminal,
3. type: ssh turtlebot@192.168.2.106
4. type: sudo service turtlebot start

ERROR MSG: turtlebot: unrecognized service

5. I also get an error when I attempt to bring up the TurtleBot Dashboard

[TurtleBot Error http://learningwebdev.com/turtlebot-error.png](http://learningwebdev.com/turtlebot-error.png)

Does anyone know where I should start in fixing these issues?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11042/turtlebot-bringup-errors/) by [comebackdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1002/comebackdan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-08-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you didn't use the TurtleBot ISO to install your laptop the service is not automatically installed. To install the service:

```
roscd turtlebot_bringup/upstart
```

Now install the service by running the install script. (the README file in the directory will also give you tips)

```
sudo ./install.bash
```

if you are using a special interface like tethering to an android tablet or using openvpn then you can provide the interface in the command line:

```
sudo ./install.bash interface(i.e. tun0 or usb0)
```

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-08-28**:
For the dashboard you need to install and run that on your workstation or run ssh with x-forwarding use the '-X' option.